# Alamofire completionHandler of responseJSON is not called

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have the following code to fetch the replies to a list of comments. (1 comment has many replies)

```
static func fetchCommentsAndTheirReplies(articleId: String, failure: (()->Void)?, success: (comments: [[String: AnyObject]], replies: [[[String: AnyObject]]], userIds: Set<String>)->Void) {
    var retComments = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    var retReplies = [[[String: AnyObject]]]()
    var retUserIds = Set<String>()

    Alamofire.request(.GET, API.listComment, parameters: [API.articleId: articleId]).responseJSON {
        response in
        guard let comments = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
            failure?()
            return
        }
        print(comments)
        retComments = comments

        let group = dispatch_group_create()

        for (commentIndex, comment) in comments.enumerate() {
            guard let id = comment["_id"] as? String else {continue}

            let relevantUserIds = parseRelaventUserIdsFromEntity(comment)
            for userId in relevantUserIds {
                retUserIds.insert(userId)
            }

            retReplies.append([[String: AnyObject]]())

            dispatch_group_enter(group)
            Alamofire.request(.GET, API.listReply, parameters: [API.commentId: id]).responseJSON {
                response in
                if let replies = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                    for (_, reply) in replies.enumerate() {

                        let relevantUserIds = parseRelaventUserIdsFromEntity(reply)
                        for userId in relevantUserIds {
                            retUserIds.insert(userId)
                        }
                    }
                    //TODO: need to capture commentIndex?
                    retReplies[commentIndex] = replies
                }
                dispatch_group_leave(group)
            }


        }

        dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
        success(comments: retComments, replies: retReplies, userIds: retUserIds)
    }
}
```

The complete handler of `API.listReply` request is never called.               `dispatch_group_enter(group)` is called once, and dispatch_group_leave(group) is never called. The code gets stuck at `dispatch_group_wait`. 
What's strange is, even the UI is stuck, which is strange because the entire function is async.

Comment: Does Alamofire use an internal serial queue? You might be deadlocking it unintentionally. You should pause execution while it's frozen to see where it's waiting.

Comment: always stop at this line:         `dispatch_group_wait(group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)`

Comment: But what else is going on? Some blocks in that group must be waiting to run.

Comment: i think it's deadlock issue. but not sure how?

Comment: Try using dispatch_group_notify instead of _wait.

Answer (score 2):

I have encounter similar problem:

on Main UI thread, call:

```
dispatch_semaphore_wait(loginDoneSemaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

and call http using Alamofire, internal also use your `httpRequest.responseJSON`

-> finally found code inside responseJSON completion handler never called

-> cause find code after DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER never called

-> finally find root cause is: Alamofire's responseJSON, default, if you not pass in the thread/queue, will run on Main UI thread

-> before call Alamofire, have inside Main UI thread, to use DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER lock UI thread

-> so following Alamofire's responseJSON, which run also on Main UI thread, will never called

-> my solution is: designate Alamofire do http response on another thread:

```
let BackgroundThread:dispatch_queue_t = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)

func dispatchBackground_async(thingsTodo:()->()) {
    dispatch_async(BackgroundThread, thingsTodo)
}

dispatchBackground_async({
    httpRequest.responseJSON(queue: BackgroundThread, completionHandler: { response in
        gLog.debug("request=\(response.request), response=\(response.response), statusCode=\(response.response?.statusCode), result=\(response.result)")
        // [Debug] [com.apple.root.background-qos] [CrifanLibHttp.swift:21]
})
```

this maybe useful for you to refer.

-> maybe you can use my method: set another thread for Alamofire's responseJSON, to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Alamofire internals, but it seems likely that it fulfills all your response completionBlocks on the same serial queue. Your `dispatch_group_wait` is blocking other responses from finishing and calling their `dispatch_group_leave`s.

You can solve this problem by using `dispatch_group_notify` instead of `dispatch_group_wait`, so rather than blocking the thread it will simply submit the block to a queue when necessary.